# Windows C dialog resizer

Tags: c, windows, winapi, dialog, resize

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144583/windows-c-dialog-resizer-class) provides lots of libraries to handle item resizing and re-adjustment, but they're all for C++. Is there anything I can use for plain C?

Comment: I'm not aware of any. Is it unacceptable to link both C++ and C objects into your project? In this case you could probably trick it into using one of the solutions provided on the linked page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call MoveWindow() do not only move but also resize Windows and Dialogs:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633534%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: I think he was looking for a library that makes it easier. See the linked page.