# How to make a MS-Visual C++ application maximize?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I want to make an app in msvc++ which will maximize on starting.When i execute my program and then maximize it by clicking on the maximize button, the windows enlarges, but the components dont resize.I'm using VC++ express edition 2005.Pls help.

Comment: Are you using the .NET designer or pure C++/WinAPI?

Comment: use ShowWindow with SW_MAXIMIZE flag.

Comment: @slugonamission , I'm using .NET designer

Comment: @Vineet Uhh.. if you're using .NET designer(WinForms) then how are you able to write C++ program? Do you mean you're using the Resource Editor for your C++ application?

Comment: i'm new to vc++, i used dev-c++ before.Sorry, i'm not using .NET designer, my fault,i'm using normal vc++.

Comment: @JosephH - have a look at C++/CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get automatically get a new paint request. Handle it.

As you perhaps already know, your Windows program should be able to paint itself at any moment. Your app may have been hidden behind another window, and when that goes away you must repaint yourself.

A side effect of this "always be ready to paint" design is that things like maximize are trivial and in fact defaulted. The default handling of "maximize" is to redraw the borders of your app, and then re-issue a paint command.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the higher level GUI frameworks (e.g. Java swing, .NET window form), as far as I know, pure win32 GUI framework does not provide a mechanism to automatically resize/reposition the controls when you resize the window. You will have to calculate the positions and the sizes of each control manually whenever the main window receives the resize notification(`WM_SIZE`).

Comment: @Vineet If you're strictly sticking with pure Win32 GUI framework, the answer is no. However, there are some alternatives. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144583/windows-c-dialog-resizer-class

Comment: I agree. In pure win32 you have to do this yourself or find code that does this for you. However a library like Qt, wxWidgets ... will provide this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CWnd::ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72szh9c7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) with SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED.

Comment: I did not downvote however I suspect the reason why you were downvoted is your answer does not address how to automatically move the controls after the window is re sized in win32 api.